# django can't find views...page not found error

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to print a response from the view.. but django shows the page not found error(404)

My main project.urls are:-

```html
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'ultimatefinalblog.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^$',views.siteindex,name="siteindex"),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^markdown/', include('django_markdown.urls')),

)
```

my blog's urls.py are:-

```html
from django.conf.urls import patterns,  url
from blog import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #url(r'^$', views.BlogIndex.as_view(), name="index"),
    #url(r'^(?P<slug>\S+)$', views.BlogDetail.as_view(), name="entry_detail"),
    #url(r'^$', views.testview, name="testview"),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>\S+)$', views.detail, name="entry_detail"),
    url(r'^testingpage/', views.testview, name='testview'),
    )
```

I have defined the testview function in my views.py

```html
def testview(request):
    return HttpResponse("testing our view!")
```

When i try to run the url 127.0.0.1:8000/blog/testingpage in my development server it shows the page not found error...can somebody help me solve this problem?

Comment: What happens if you try with /blog/testingpage/ instead of /blog/testingpage?

Comment: Does the error page displays some URL patterns?

Comment: Do you have this error with other URLS? Could you add your settings.py file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is your issue:

In your URL patterns,

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>\S+)$', views.detail, name="entry_detail"),
url(r'^testingpage/', views.testview, name='testview'),
```

The `testingpage` is being matched with `?P<slug>\S+` (for `views.detail`), before `views.testview`, and you probably have a `raise 404` or something similar line of code to match slug.

So, Change the order:

```
url(r'^testingpage/', views.testview, name='testview'),
url(r'^(?P<slug>\S+)$', views.detail, name="entry_detail"),
```

And it should work for you.

Also, Slug is generally matched with `(?P<slug>[\w-]+)` and not `\S+`

Comment: Thank you so much..i was able to solve my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

So!
I succeded to make your code work.

I'll organize this answer in *three parts* (beware : It will be exhaustive!) :

- First :

I'll copy the code I made (almost the same as yours, plus the parts you didn't provide and I had to recode - these are very basic, just to fill the missing parts). I hope it will help you to find how to fix your problem by comparing. I'll also give an hypothesis about your problem.

- Second :

I'll talk about your code. There are good habits that could help you to build your django projects (but you don't seem to use these). Please note that your code can work without using these. But it may be more difficult without these habits.

- Third :

I will suggest a corrected version of your code with comments to illustrate the second part.

## First - The code that works on my computer :

I make my own version of your project with *django 1.7.5*.
I organized the project like this :

```
.
├── blog
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── main
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── manage.py
```

Where "*main*" is the project name and "*blog*" an app.

From a fresh project, the files I had to modify/add are :

**blog/urls.py :**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns,  url
from blog import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       #url(r'^$', views.BlogIndex.as_view(), name="index"),
                       #url(r'^(?P<slug>\S+)$', views.BlogDetail.as_view(), name="entry_detail"),
                       #url(r'^$', views.testview, name="testview"),
                       url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
                       url(r'^(?P<slug>\S+)$', views.detail, name="entry_detail"),
                       url(r'^testingpage/', views.testview, name='testview'),
)
```

**blog/views.py :**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def testview(request):
    return HttpResponse("testing our view!")

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Index.")

def detail(request, slug="test"):
    return HttpResponse("Detail : " + slug)
```

**main/urls.py :**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'main.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^$',views.siteindex,name="siteindex"),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^markdown/', include('django_markdown.urls')),
)
```

**main/views.py :**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def siteindex(request):
    return HttpResponse("site index!")
```

Then I just do :

```
>>>python manage.py migrate
>>>python manage.py runserver
```

And I can access to http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/testingpage/ and to other pages. I have no problem this way.

But I you do so, you will see that this URL matches with the `r'^(?P<slug>\S+)$'` pattern. And therefore */blog/testingpage* does not trigger the view *testview* but the view *detail*.
So I think your problem may come from the *detail* view, could you add it to your question to check?

## Second - How you could improve your code :

- apps and views imports

The way you imports your views is functionnal, but it could be impractible
You could add the app ("*blog*") containing your views to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your *main/settings.py*. And you will be able to use your views just by entering their names as strings.

*edit :*

[This changed with the 1.8 release](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#django-conf-urls-patterns), now it's recommended to do like you did. My bad.

- Your project isn't an app.

Your */main/urls.py* suggests that you've a views.py in your */main* directory.
Using this directory this way isn't explicitly forbidden, but it's an app's purpose. the */main* directory is meant to contain general settings.
I think you should make a second app for your *views.py* (and probably some url patterns) if you don't want to insert it in the "*blog*" app.

- urlpatterns order

With your *blog/urls.py* file, your app will "works". But */blog/testingpage/* will trigger the *detail* view and not the *testview* view, I'm not sure that is what you want to do. Beware the patterns order!

## Third - An other way to do this :

Here is my version of the code.
I have organized the project like this :

```
.
├── blog
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── main
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
└── website
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── admin.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

The new files are :

**blog/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
# You don't need this anymore
# from blog import views 

urlpatterns = patterns('blog.views',  # this first argument will be used as a prefix to locate your views.
                       url(r'^$', 'index' , name="index"),
                       # beware the order!
                       # url(r'^(?P<slug>\S+)$', views.detail, name="entry_detail"),
                       url(r'^testingpage/', 'testview', name='testview'),
                       url(r'^(?P<slug>\S+)$', 'detail', name="entry_detail"),
)
```

**blog/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def testview(request):
    return HttpResponse("testing our view!")

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Index.")

def detail(request, slug="test"):
    return HttpResponse("Detail : " + slug)
```

**INSTALLED_APP in main/settings.py (/!\ Important /!\)**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
    'website',
)
```

**main/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'main.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^markdown/', include('django_markdown.urls')),
    url(r'^$', include('website.urls')),
)
```

**website/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
# If you add the app name to INSTALLED_APP you don't need this anymore.
# from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('website.views', # This first argument will be used as a prefix to locate your views.
    url(r'^$', 'siteindex', name="siteindex"),
)
```

**website/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def siteindex(request):
    return HttpResponse("site index!")
```

I hope all of this will help.

Comment: Thank you..my problem was the order of urls in the blog's urls.py....now it is solved :)